# create a Div that automatically takes on attributes defined by id

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, rss

I have an a div that gets dynamic information (rss feeds) via its id (id="rss-feeds") from the plugin called jQuery-rss like so

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/tar-home?format=xml", {
      limit: 1,
      effect: 'slideFastSynced'
    });
  });
```

I'm trying to create the Div via JQuery so that when I click a button, a Div with the id="rss-feeds" gets created and automatically inherits the characteristics of the id as well as the contents, which is the feeds from the plugin.

The html is like this

```
<button name="tech">Technology</button>
```

the js I'm using is this

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $("button[name='tech']").click(function(){

      var create = ('<div id="rss-feeds"></div>');
      $(this).after(create);
    });
});
```

What happens is that a Div is created but it doesn't take on the css styling I attributed to id="rss-feeds" neither does it have the contents, its just invisible but when i inspect it, i can see that its there,

how can I go about this?

Comment: Please provide all your code, as it certainly will not work if you run the RSS feeds code first :)

Comment: you can't create elements with same ID, use `class` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the rss function **after** you've created the rss div.

```
function populateRss(){
    $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/tar-home?format=xml", {
      limit: 1,
      effect: 'slideFastSynced'
    });
}

$("button[name='tech']").click(function(){
    var create = ('<div id="rss-feeds"></div>');
    $(this).after(create);
    populateRss();
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i still cannot get it to work guys, the code for the jQuery-rss is this here  [link](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss/blob/gh-pages/src/jquery.rss.js) and i'm using thier default set up see here [link](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss#setup) , @TrueBlueAussie

Comment: i decided not to complicate things and use the show and hide div on clicking a button, works the same for my project without the headache.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call rss() function after you have created div.

Your click handler should look something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $("button[name='tech']").click(function(){
      var create = ('<div id="rss-feeds"></div>');

      $(create).rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/tar-home?format=xml", {
         limit: 1,
         effect: 'slideFastSynced'
      });

      $(this).after(create);
    });
});
```